# I can't connect to ethernet network

Tags: networking, dual-boot, internet, ethernet

Good night guys. I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS today, but I can't connect to the network. Yes, I've already searched Google for solutions and nothing, including many of them on the Ubuntu forum itself. I'm running the system in dual boot with Windows 10 on different storage units. Windows on an SSD and Ubuntu on an ordinary mechanical HD. My motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-970 Gaming, with an FX 8320e CPU. Anyway, I would be forever grateful if someone could help, really. Thanks.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `lspci`? This will show information about your hardware, making it more likely that someone can offer some specific assistance that will get your network device working 

Comment: @matigo May I suggest: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`

Answer (score 1):

So, guys, I managed to solve the problem. Added the iommu=soft command to GRUB_LINUX_CMD_LINE="". It turns out that I had to disable IOMMU in the BIOS when I installed the system, since being enabled Ubuntu didn't recognize my USB devices. I found this out after running the command "sudo dmesg | grep -i eth" in the terminal and seeing that I had a error message with the network card. I researched and found this solution that I mentioned at the beginning. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!